# EF Core - Passar parâmetro com lista de números inteiros

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Estou tentando executar uma consulta passando como cláusula um 'in' com números inteiros, este é o código até o momento:

```
public List<Pedido> GetByUsuario(List<GestorVendedor> gestorVendedor)
{
    int[] seller_id = new int[gestorVendedor.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < gestorVendedor.Count; i++)
    {
        seller_id[i] = gestorVendedor[i].id;
    }

    return _dbContext.Pedido.FromSql("select * from dbo.vendas where seller_id in ({0})", String.Join(",", seller_id)).ToList();
}
```

Com este código ocorre problema na conversão como mostra a mensagem de erro:

**'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.'**

Como contornar este problema?

Comment: Faça um teste:
string query = $"select * from dbo.vendas where seller_id in ({String.Join(",", seller_id)})"

Você está dando um um .ToList() no FromSql().ToList()

Comment: Olá Geilton, executou como você passou, no entanto, ele dá um alerta de vulnerabilidade de injeção! Desculpa alongar mais existe uma maneira correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duas questões que posso considerar no seu código:

```
int[] seller_id = new int[gestorVendedor.Count];
```

Mude para:

```
var seller_ids = gestorVendedor.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```

Para fazer a consulta eu não usaria o `FromSql` e sim passaria a consulta via `linq` que fica bem mais fácil:

```
return _dbContext.Pedido.Where(x => seller_ids.Contains(x.seller_id)).ToList();
```

O EF já montara a query com os parametros in e passa para o banco.

Comment: Estou me acostumando com EF...hehe, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado...

Answer (score 4):

Você não precisa usar uma *query* `SQL` se já está usando o EF.

```
public List<Pedido> GetByUsuario(List<GestorVendedor> gestorVendedor)
{ 
    return _dbContext.Pedido.Where(p=> gestorVendedor.Select(x => x.GestorVendedorId).ToArray().Contains(p.SellerId)).ToList()
}
```

Você transforma a lista em Array e utiliza o `Contains`

obs: Não sei se a sua propriedade chama `SellerId`, talvez você tenha que ajustar

Comment: não sei se passar a lista `gestorVendedor.ToArray()` diretamente para o comando irá funcionar, pois o que você passa no where o EF vai transformar em SQL para o banco. Por isso acho importante montar a lista de array com os ids antes.

Comment: Não prestei atenção que era uma lista de objetos, ajustei a resposta